# which port visual studio use for web deployment?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-deployment

I have a mvc project in visual studio in my local computer. And I am trying to deploy it in my school network. Some ports are blocked in my school network.

I can easily deploy my project at home. But in school I get this error

> Error 5   Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote
>   computer ("mydomain.com"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web
>   Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management
>   Service") is started.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.)

which port does visual studio use for web deployment? Because port 80 is available.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Web Deploy uses ports 80 and 8172](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy).